# Passing an int from an activity to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using the following code on my activity:

public class SongSing extends Activity implements SongCommunicator{

```
int lang, level;
static SongFragment2 fragment2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    lang = extras.getInt("lang");
    level = extras.getInt("level");

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("lang", lang);
    Fragment f = new Fragment();
    f.setArguments(b);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_song_sing);

}
```

and my fragment:

public class SongFragment1 extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

```
int lang, level;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.song_fragment1, null);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle != null){
        lang = bundle.getInt("lang");
    }
```

But I get a null bundle.

any idea why?

thanks!

Comment: `Fragment f = new Fragment();` why are you instantiating a generic fragment? You have your own `SongFragment1`, use it instead.

Comment: You create a fragment instance, you add the arguments but then you stop. You should now pass this information to your fragment (transaction).

Comment: argh... I'm new to fragments. I have a song

Comment: hit the wrong button.. I have a song_sing.xml which afaik instantiate my fragments. How would you pass simply data from an activity.

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern to create a Fragment is the one one shown below:

```
/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param broadcast to watch
 * @return A new instance of fragment LivePlayerFragment.
 */
public static LivePlayerFragment newInstance(Broadcast broadcast) {
    LivePlayerFragment fragment = new LivePlayerFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(PARAM_BROADCAST, broadcast);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public LivePlayerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
```

As you can see, you have a Static method to build the fragment with the appropriate arguments. Play attention to the empty constructor. This is mandatory for the Fragments, to let the system recall it when necessary

After this, you can get the arguments when you want in the onCreateView or OnCreate methods...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that provided input!
I found a clean solution by invoking a method on the fragment side. simple stupid great.
I recommend reading the following article:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments